# How would i prevent incorrect entry from access? And how would i iterate a function from string comparing only the top line?

Tags: c

This is a sample on a program I am working on. In the file I created is called user.txt The variables are stored as (User: %s Password: %s). In the program when launched, if I enter the correct parameters the program continues fine but if I enter an incorrect parameter it proceeds regardless to the other aspects of the program. How would I prevent the access of incorrect users/passwords? And assuming the users.txt file has multiple lines consisting of (User: %s Password: %s), how would I get the Login function to loop for checking serveral lines instead of the top line?

Some contents in the users.txt file are:

User: 1738 Password: 12AA

User: 1092 Password: Jason15

User: 1111 Password: 19962001

User: 31268 Password: Midas12

```
int main()
{
        char user[30],pass[30],Access='N';
        int result=0;
        while(Access=='N'){

            char user[30], pass[30];

            printf("\nUser:");
            scanf("%s",user);
            printf("\nPassword:");
            scanf("%s",pass);

            Login(user, pass);
            if(result=1){
                Access='Y';
            }
        }
        printf("You have access.\n");
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
}

int Login(char user[30], char pass[30]){
        FILE *p;
        char user2[30], pass2[30];
        int i=0,result=0;

        p= fopen("users.txt", "r");

        while(i!=EOF){
            fscanf(p,"User: %s Password: %s",user2,pass2);

            if( (strcmp(user,user2)==0) && (strcmp(pass,pass2)==0) ){
                printf("\nUser and password correct!!!\n\n");
                fclose(p);
                result==1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(result=0){
            printf("\nUser or password incorrect!\n\n");
        }
        printf("\n");

        fclose(p);
        return result;
}
```

Comment: Multiple problems. `Login(user, pass); if(result=1){`. The `Login` function is not defined to return anything. And even if it did, you are not storing the return value into `result`. The `Login` function actually does have `return` statements in it. But the function is not defined to return anything - that's what `void` means in `void Login(char user[30], char pass[30])`. That's just for starters.

Comment: `if(result=1)` needs to be `if(result==1)`. And why bother with another `Access` variable as you can just use `result` directly (once it actually stores the right value)?

Comment: Than you. If i chose to have multiple usernames and password would i need an iteration after before the fscanf and before the final return? How would i achieve that? (without multiple printings of "User or password incorrect"

Comment: Use a loop with `fgets` (or `fscanf`) to read one line of the file at a time. `break` the loop if the entered credentials match the line. If the loop completes without a match then print the user msg.

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your question and post an excerpt from the contents of file `user.txt` ?

Comment: Basically just put a loop around the `fscanf` and `if` block (but not the `else` part which should be outside the loop).

Comment: I made an edit with a sample of the users.txt file.

Comment: If an error is made now the program freezes, i edited the program to what i have currently

Comment: You never assign anything to the variable `i` inside the `while` loop, so it will never be equal to `EOF`